# vimscript: how to call a function in insert mode?

Tags: vim

in vim insert mode:

```
module:function|
               ^
               cursor at here
```

I wanna press combined key (e.g. `C-z`) to delete the `function`.

```
module:|
       ^
       cursor at here
```

The key point is that: **can not exit the insert mode**

how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

directly input: `<C-o>db`

`<C-o>`will execute a normal command,then back to insert.

You may add a map to execute directly:

```
ino <C-z> <C-o>db
```

By the way, there is a built-in key:`<C-w>`, which backwards delete word.